# Excel VBA Insert copied cells syntax

Tags: excel, vba

The goal of my macro is too simply copy the cells of any row that has the value 1 in it and insert that same value into another row right above it. The only caveat is I also have values in columns B & C so I want those copied and inserted as well. My macro is below

I have recognized that the problem is excel is taking Columns AR as opposed to the range AR but I'm having a bit of trouble getting around this as I cant think of naming my R variable another way to bypass the problem.

Thanks a ton for the help!

```
Sub BlankLine()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

    Col = "A"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, Col) = "1" Then
                .Range("AR:CR").Copy
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by range AR? AR is the definition of a column in excel.

Comment: You're right my apologies for the confusion. I was a bit flustered for the moment and am realizing the folly of what I wrote. Danesjai solved it though. His code copies every row that has a 1 in column a and inserts it into a new row right above it(limits the copied rows to include only cells that have an actual value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** I changed the code to just copy those three columns (A to C) then insert a new row then set the values to those three columns. Comments are in the code. If you want to copy more columns, just change the integer in the `dupRange` variable (i.e., the **2** in `.Cells(R, Col + 2))`)

```
Sub BlankLines()

Dim Col As Integer
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

Col = 1 'changed to number
StartRow = 2 'changed to 2 since you have a header
BlankRows = 1 'not used in this code...

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    For R = LastRow To StartRow Step -1
        If .Cells(R, Col) = "1" Then
            Dim dupRange As Variant 'array to store values
            Set dupRange = .Range(.Cells(R, Col), .Cells(R, Col + 2)) 'store the column values for the row
            .Rows(R & ":" & R).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert the new row
            c = 0 'to increment over the copied columns
            For Each v In dupRange
                .Cells(R, Col + c) = v 'sets the array values to each column
                c = c + 1
            Next v
        End If
    Next R
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Give this a try. Not 100% sure if this is what you're after.

Comment: Amazing exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much Daneshjai! Your entire code was perfect with the exception for my purposes I made my startrow =2 :D Thanks again!!!

Comment: Apologies but I need just a bit of futher help. Your code copies the entire row. If I say I values in other columns is there any way to copy say the values in columns a-c for each row only?

Comment: Updated the code. Should do what you're looking for now.